# d3.xml broken after upgrade to v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this bit of code that was working on d3 v4 but is broken after upgrading to v5 it fails with the error

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_d3__.G(...).mimeType is not a function
```

The code:

```
Object.keys(Constants.images).forEach(imageName => {
  console.log(imageName, Constants.images[imageName])
  d3
    .xml(Constants.images[imageName])
    .mimeType('image/svg+xml')
    .get((error, xml) => {
      if (error) throw error;

      let svgElement = xml.documentElement;
      svgElement.id = `def-${imageName}`;
      this.defs.node().appendChild(svgElement);
    });

  this.defs.selectAll('svg').attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'none');
});
```

Constants.images[imageName] contains a url which points to an svg

The error seems to be about the line `.xml(Constants.images[imageName])` since commenting out the mimetypes line causes it to move to the .get line. What could be causing this to fail after the upgrade from v4 to v5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove .mimetype and convert .get to the new syntax

```
Object.keys(Constants.images).forEach(imageName => {
  d3
    .xml(Constants.images[imageName])
    .then((xml) => {
      let svgElement = xml.documentElement;
      svgElement.id = `def-${imageName}`;
      this.defs.node().appendChild(svgElement);
    });

  this.defs.selectAll('svg').attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you were using the [d3-request](https://github.com/d3/d3-request) module, which was superseded by [d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) in v5.

d3-fetch basically acts as a wrapper around the Fetch API. It provides parsing for D3 on top of the [Fetch API](https://github.com/d3/d3-request). The Fetch API is used in lieu of the older `XMLHttpRequest` (used in d3-request), and uses `Promise`s to handle asynchronous requests.

Since D3 now uses d3-fetch, the signature of `d3.xml` has changed in v5.

From the documentation:

> `d3.xml(input[,init])`: Fetches the file at the specified input URL as
>   text and then parses it as XML. If init is specified, it is passed
>   along to the underlying call to fetch; see RequestInit for allowed
>   fields.

So if you must specify a MIME type, you could specify it as a header it in the `init`. Something like:

```
d3.xml(Constants.images[imageName], {
  headers: [
    ["Content-Type", "image/svg+xml"],
  ]
})
```